# Efficiently delete columns based on mismatch from large tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 tables with schema that look like this:

```
key, host, file, mtimes
key, host
```

I have to delete all rows from table 1 when the key is same as table 2 but hosts are different.

table 1 (25 million row):

```
k1, h0, file0, 0
k1, h1, file1, 0
k1, h2, file1, 1
k2, h3, file1, 2
k2, h3, file2, 3
k3, h4, file3, 4
```

table 2 (300k rows):

```
k1, h0
k2, h3
k3, h4
```

result:

```
k1, h0, file0, 0
k2, h3, file1, 2
k2, h3, file2, 3
k3, h4, file3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `delete` with a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
delete from table1
    where exists (select
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.key = table1.key and t2.host <> t1.host
                 );
```

If you just want to select the rows that meet you condition, the query is similar:

```
select table1.*
from table1
where not exists (select
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.key = table1.key and t2.host <> t1.host
                 );
```

For performance on either of these you want an index on `table2(key, host)`.

Comment: would it be performant for such large table? I ran a similar query and it was basically stuck forever.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many options to chose from in SQLite for this case.
You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete from table1 
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from table2 t2
  where t2.key = table1.key and t2.host = table1.host
);
```

A composite index on `(key, host)` in both tables would help.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bA2SJiLx1JjfP9zetyQsq/0).
Results:

```
| key | host | file  | mtimes |
| --- | ---- | ----- | ------ |
| k1  | h0   | file0 | 0      |
| k2  | h3   | file1 | 2      |
| k2  | h3   | file2 | 3      |
| k3  | h4   | file3 | 4      |
```

Comment: Do you think it will perform okay for a large table like this?

Comment: I can't think of any other option for this requirement with what SQLite offers. So set the indexes and then test it.